# h5p activity examples categories

Tags: filter

On https://www.h5p.org > `Examples & Downloads page` https://h5p.org/content-types-and-applications under the `Content Types` heading: What is the difference between the `Larger Resources` and `Tasks` filter categories? I first thought that they are separating single activities and bundled  activities (like the `Quiz/Question set` type), but they put `Quiz/Questions set` under `Tasks`. I would post this question on the h5p website forum, but it won't let me log in at the moment. Does someone know more about those categories?

Comment: I assume that there were plans to establish a refined category system, but that it was simply not maintained well due to other things being of higher priority.

Comment: So the filters are basically not helpful at the moment?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.